# Add text to display area via click and convert that value to JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am stuck on something I had gotten to work in CodePen and JSFiddle but still won't work when testing in my actual page.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="textinput">Add Item:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">

              <input id="textinput" name="textinput" class="input-large" type="text">
              <button id="add-button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add <img class="caret" src="img/caret.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Text output-->
        <div class="col-md-3 json-output">
          <p>JSON:</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div id="json"></div>


        </div>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add-button').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

        var inputVal =  $('#textinput').val();
          $('#json').html(inputVal);

    });

  });
```

I want to be able to enter text in add item and click Add to add to a field below. I originally had another input field but that wasn't working at all so I left it as a div right now which works on and off on jsfiddle. Here that is: http://jsfiddle.net/gV5Pt/16/

The second part I want to do is once the text is entered I would like that value to be in JSON format.

I hope I'm on the right track here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

**1. To get the add button to work properly.**

Don't *set* the html of the `#json` div, *append* it:

```
var $json = $('#json').append('<p>' + inputVal + '</p>'); 
//or use other tags, or leave them off altogether and append a comma, etc...
```

**2. Conversion to JSON**

This will all depend on what format you are looking for. JSON is a key-value structure. You already got the values, so what do you want as keys? To get you started, I'll build up a script to get you a JSON with one key and the values you  entered:

```
var json = { values: []};

$('#json').each(function(i, e) {
    json.values.push($(e).find('p').text());
});
```

Of course, how you can get the values depends on how you append them in the first place. You could use `$(e).find('p').text().split(',')` if you're making a comma separated list for example instead of using `p` tags. I'll leave it up to you, but hopefully I have given you a push in the right direction.

Comment: Definitely a good start! I had seen .html and .append used for this before. I wanted to get the JSON and then take that and display an ordered list when you click another (load JSON) button.

Comment: @user2073592 why don't you just build an ordered list right away? You can have an `<ol id="json">` ready and then when you click the add button, `$('#json').append('<li>' + inputVal + '</li>');`